# How to make wine with green vine grapes?

Tags: wine

We cut down 10-15 clusters of vine grapes straight from a vine in Mallorca, Spain in July. They are green, still hard and bitter and about half an inch size.
What procedure should I follow to make wine with these grapes? What are the best ingredients (type of sugar, yield, water, etc)? What is the most efficient  temperature for fermentation? How long should I let them ferment? Should I wait for grapes to get softer? Please advise.

Comment: I won't add this yet as an answer, but I have my own grapevines. If you want to make wine from grapes, you need to let them ripe into september/october. You can't make good wine from unripe grapes, it will taste too vegetal. The ripening process is more than becoming sweet, it changes the composition of the grape and its peel too.